# Modx установка google analytics и яндекс метрики

Tags: modx, google-analytics, yandex-metrika-api

Можно ли установить оные на динамические страницы? Начальство сказало переделать динамические страницы на статические, чтобы подключить сервисы, есть у кого-то подобный опыт с различными CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кладешь код аналитики в шаблон и все работает.
Можно создать чанк, и вызывать его на динамических страницах.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую добавить